# How to create a re-sizable and draggable UITextView in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift3

I am creating a notes application in which user can add any number of text views and the views will have borders (like image below) so that a user can resize it.
[image]

I am thinking to create a UIBezierPath, but I don't know how to add gesture recognizers on UIBezierPath.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show the code you've been working on. If you don't have any code yet, give it a try, and then come back if you have specific questions. If you haven't even *looked* for a way to do this yet, that's your first step. Here's is just the first result I got when searching for `ios swift resize handles` ---   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819603/how-can-i-add-sizing-handles-to-a-uiview

Comment: @DonMag thanks for your help, I want SPUserResizableView in Swift 3. I am going to try it.